# How to compare and order list by date/time in java?

Tags: java, date, comparator

How do i implement a java comparator class which can sort the order of the list of date/time strings?

Like e.g.

i have

```
2012-06-15T12:01:00.000+08:00
2012-06-25T12:15:00.000+08:00
2012-06-08T00:00:00.000Z
```

Then it should be sorted like

```
2012-06-08T00:00:00.000Z
2012-06-15T12:01:00.000+08:00
2012-06-25T12:15:00.000+08:00
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have *two* issues here (since parsing the strings directly is not going to work).

1. Convert your strings into dates. See [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info and the [DateFormat.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method
2. Sort the subsequent dates in a collection using [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 2):

Parse them into `java.util.Date`. Date already implements `Comparable`

Answer (score 0):

well, If you want a quick solution, it is as follows.

http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/NITE/nxt/apidoc/net/sourceforge/nite/util/SortedList.html.

Also, if you are confidant every date will be different, then do use TreeSet.You can use them as follows.

Make a new TreeSet and keep adding your dates in them. It will be automatically sorted, As TreeSet sorts all objects it contains, if they implement comparable.(or comparator provided).